# Android: Error identifier expected

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, I require your help
I am creating a shopping list app and in my ServerConnect.java file is giving many errors, request you to please advice me in correcting the code , the errors come as Error identifier expected or illigal start of type
Thank you in advance for your help

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;


public abstract class ServerConnect {
private GetFromServer getFromServer;
public ServerConnect(Context context,HashMap<String,String> payloads){
    getFromServer = new GetFromServer(context,getUrlEncoder(payloads));
}

public void execute(String url){
    getFromServer.execute(url);
}

private String getUrlEncoder(HashMap<String,String> payloads){
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

    for (HashMap.Entry<String,String> temp: payloads.entrySet()){
        Log.w("HM", temp.getKey() + "," + temp.getValue());
        builder.appendQueryParameter(temp.getKey(),temp.getValue());
    }

    return builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

}

public abstract void getResult(String result);

private class GetFromServer extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String urlEncodedPayLoads;
    public GetFromServer(Context context,String urlEncodedPayLoads){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Wait","Connecting Server");
        this.urlEncodedPayLoads = urlEncodedPayLoads;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String… params) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connected, Please wait");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTf-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(urlEncodedPayLoads);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));

            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        getResult(s);
    }
}

}
```

Please see logcat error below

Please find the error log below

```
Error:(65, 47) error: illegal character: '\u2026'
Error:(65, 48) error: ';'expected
Error:(65, 55) error: illegal start of type
Error:(65, 56) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(65, 58) error: ';' expected
Error:(66, 40) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(67, 38) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(67, 39) error: illegal start of type
Error:(68, 13) error: illegal start of type
Error:(68, 16) error: ';' expected
Error:(71, 51) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(71, 52) error: illegal start of type
Error:(72, 52) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(72, 53) error: illegal start of type
Error:(73, 49) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(73, 50) error: illegal start of type
Error:(74, 53) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(74, 54) error: illegal start of type
Error:(74, 70) error: illegal start of type
Error:(75, 45) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(75, 46) error: illegal start of type
Error:(76, 46) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(76, 47) error: illegal start of type
Error:(81, 37) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(81, 56) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(82, 37) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(83, 37) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(84, 35) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(86, 42) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(94, 17) error: illegal start of type
Error:(94, 24) error: illegal start of type
Error:(94, 25) error: ')' expected
Error:(94, 29) error: ';' expected
Error:(94, 55) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(94, 57) error: ';' expected
Error:(98, 15) error: illegal start of type
Error:(100, 15) error: illegal start of type
Error:(102, 15) error: illegal start of type
Error:(106, 13) error: illegal start of type
Error:(106, 19) error: ';' expected
Error:(106, 33) error: illegal start of type
Error:(111, 19) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(113, 13) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(114, 13) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(115, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Comment: add full logcat please

Comment: Kindly see i have added the logcat error while compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have copied/pasted this code from somewhere.

```
protected String doInBackground(String… params)
```

is invalid, specifically the ellipsis character after `String`. That should be three dots, such as:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

It's difficult to conceive that all those red highlights of your broken code didn't give you enough help.